# How do I create an identicon for email?

Tags: c#, .net

how to create identicon for email with c#?

Comment: please don't use "Hello" or "Thanks", and don't add a signature. This is not a discussion forum, so we're not having a pleasant chat.

Comment: ok i will try to do so. i dont know the rules here, thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/), [Unicornify](http://unicornify.appspot.com/), or another free online identicon solution.

Otherwise:

- Hash the e-mail address, for example by xor-ing all letters together.
- Encode this to some small set of numbers, for example 8 numbers between 0 and 15.
- Use each number in some way in the image. For example, one or two number for color, a number for size or shape of some part of the image, etc.

Comment: can i use gravatar generated icons for commercial websites?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://identicon.codeplex.com/